# How to loop through a json string with PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

My example only returns `BMW 2010`.
How do I get it to return `AUDI 2000` and `BMW 2010`?

```
declare
    sample_json   varchar2 (32767)
        := '

            [{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}]
';
begin
    apex_json.parse (sample_json);
    dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('NAME'));
    dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('YEAR'));
end;
```

Comment: As per JSON standard (RFC7159) : *"The names within an object SHOULD be unique."*  and it is not recommended to use same key within the same JSON path. Your json should have ideally have been something like `[{  "NAME":"AUDI" , "YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"]`  , i.e an array of jsons. Then it becomes easier to parse it. In it's present state, the json functions are bound to parse the first key,value pair.

Comment: `{[{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}]}` is invalid JSON as the outer `{}` does not have a key/value pair. You want something like `{"data":[{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}]}`or just to remove the outer curly braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR - You cannot as you have duplicate keys in an object.

---

[From JSON Standard - RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6)

> 4. Objects
>
> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
> from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
> name.  **The names within an object SHOULD be unique.**

*(Added emphasis)*

```
{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000","NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}
```

While technically it is syntactically correct JSON, it does not make sense as you are duplicating keys so most (every) JSON parsers following RFC 7159 will overwrite the first instance of a key with later occurrences so your JSON is effectively:

```
{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}
```

And you cannot get `AUDI`/`2000` from the output (unless you parse the JSON by hand).

If you want to send multiple values then you should use an array:

```
[{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}]
```

---

**Update**

You can try:

```
declare
  sample_json varchar2(32767) := '{"data":[{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}]}';
begin
  apex_json.parse (sample_json);
  dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('data[1].NAME'));
  dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('data[1].YEAR'));
  dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('data[2].NAME'));
  dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('data[2].YEAR'));
end;
```

or (if apex will accept an array as its outer object):

```
declare
    sample_json varchar2(32767) := '[{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}]';
begin
  apex_json.parse (sample_json);
  FOR i IN 1 .. 2 LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path=>'[%d].NAME',p0=>i));
    dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path=>'[%d].YEAR',p0=>i));
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, my mistake in question i have in sample json [{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}]  how use loop?

Comment: and I don't know how many items will be in the array?

Answer (score 5):

Since you're running Oracle 12c, you don't need Apex_json. You may use standard Oracle's JSON functions.

```
set serveroutput on
declare
sample_json   varchar2 (32767)
        := '[{"NAME":"AUDI","YEAR":"2000"},{"NAME":"BMW","YEAR":"2010"}]';
BEGIN
for rec IN (
     select j.name,j.year 
       from json_table(sample_json,'$[*]' COLUMNS 
        name varchar2(20) PATH '$.NAME',
        year NUMBER       PATH '$.YEAR'
       ) j  ) 
     LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line (rec.name||','||rec.year);
     END LOOP;
END;
/



AUDI,2000
BMW,2010


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```